# Opengl Window with mouse control for win 32

Tags: windows, opengl, mouse, camera, graphic

I am new to OpenGl, almost new to C++.

I am looking for some code that does the following things.

1. Open an OpenGL window (maybe using glut)
2. Rotate the view point when the user press the left mouse button
3. zoom when the user press the right mouse button
4. translate the point of view the user press the central button

Basically what I need is a very simple graphics platform in which I will plot results coming from my algorithms. I have tried using the glut library and some code coming from the web, but no luck!

This should be a basic project, can you please point me where to find it. It just seems unreal to me that a so simple project turns to be so hard to find, but I have been googling for hours and no results.

I really appreciate your help,

thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You're asking for a fair amount of code there. Basic, but not insubstantial. Even if we do provide the code to do what you've asked, I'm not sure if you'll be able to use it to do what you want. The Red Book is a "bible" of openGL programming of sorts and will provide you with many of the functions and how to use them. I found the entire thing online [here](http://fly.cc.fer.hr/~unreal/theredbook/). Look into Chapters 1-3 for your drawing and rotating. Also, Lighthouse 3D has some great tutorials for you to look at for mouse events ([Link](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/opengl/glut/index.php?9)). Some knowledge of linear algebra really helps, but you can manage without it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it directly implements everything you want, but you might want to look at the [3D graph control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/openGL/ntgraph3d_atl.aspx) on Code Project. This is hardly unique though -- you might want to Google for something like "opengl activex" and look at some of the alternatives. I doubt any will directly implement all you've asked for -- they'll probably include most of the basic operations, but it'll be up to you to make the connection between the mouse operations and the actions in the window.